# How to get a key from inside another key in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Hey does anybody know how I would go about getting the value of a key which is already inside another key like this:

```
a = {"fruit":[{"oranges":['10']},{"apples":['11']}]}
print(a.get("fruit"))
```

I can get the value of "fruit" but how would I get the value of "oranges".
Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: `a['fruit'][0]['oranges']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's format your dictionary and clearly see what you have:

```py
a = {
  "fruit": [
    {
      "oranges": ['10']
    },
    {
      "apples": ['11']
    }
  ]
}
```

So, `a.get('fruit')` gives you a `list`, which elements can be accessed with indexes.

---

So `a['fruit'][0]` gives you

```py
{
  "oranges": ['10']
}
```

and `a['fruit'][1]` gives you

```py
{
  "apples": ['11']
}
```

---

So in order to get the value of `oranges` you should go with:

```
a['fruit'][0]['oranges']
```

which will give you: `['10']`. `['10']` is a list of its own. If you want to get only the value, you can do:

```
a['fruit'][0]['oranges'][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to access the first element of the list inside fruits, and then access the key inside

```
print(a['fruit'][0]['oranges']
```